# Unhandled exception at ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, sdl

I'm using Visual Studio 2011 C++ with boost v1.52.0 Just added method to search for file in sub directories and started to get this error on program close:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7733E3BE (ntdll.dll) in Platformer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x437FEF0C.
```

FileSystem.h:

```
#ifndef FILESYSTEM_H
#define FILESYSTEM_H

#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

namespace fs=boost::filesystem;

class FileSystem
{
public:
    static const std::string GetExePath();
    static const std::string GetFullPath(std::string fileName, std::string searchInPath = "");
};

#endif
```

FileSystem.cpp

```
#include "FileSystem.h"

const std::string FileSystem::GetExePath()
{
    fs::path path = fs::current_path();
    return path.string();
}

const std::string FileSystem::GetFullPath(std::string fileName, std::string searchInPath)
{
    if(searchInPath == "") 
    {
        searchInPath = GetExePath();
    }

    fs::directory_iterator end_iter;
    for( fs::directory_iterator dir_iter(searchInPath); dir_iter!=end_iter; ++dir_iter)
    {
        if(fs::is_directory(dir_iter->status()))
        {
            return GetFullPath(fileName, dir_iter->path().string());
        }
        else if (fs::is_regular_file(dir_iter->status()))
        {
            if(dir_iter->path().filename() == fs::path(fileName).filename())
            {
                return dir_iter->path().string();
            }
        }
    }

    return std::string("");
}
```

And I use it in that way:

```
std::string imageFullPath = FileSystem::GetFullPath("image.png");
```

What is wrong with this code? Thanks.

Comment: did you try and debug your code?

Comment: My guess is that you are dereferencing an invalid iterator. Is your `end_itr` correct? Shouldn't you set it somewhere? That would explain everything: if your range is empty then dereferencing `dir_iter` invokes exactly that behavior you see.

Comment: Since you're crashing when the program is closing: are you *certain* that the crash is caused by this code? It sounds odd to retrieve the full path of a PNG while closing the program.

Comment: I'm certain, that crash is caused by the method FileSystem::GetFullPath("image.png") If I do not use this method program closes without any error.

Comment: The interesting thing that is crashes when program is build in debug mode. If its build in release, then program closes without crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I didn't mentioned that I was using SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) libraries. These libraries were linked using #pragma comment (lib, ...) That causes errors on the application closing. I defined them in Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies section ant the problem was solved.

Secondly GetFullPath method was wrong. Here is the correct one:

```
const std::string FileSystem::GetFullPath(std::string fileName, std::string searchInPath)
{
    std::string result;

    if(searchInPath.empty()) {
        searchInPath = GetExePath();
    }

    fs::directory_iterator end_iter;
    for( fs::directory_iterator dir_iter(searchInPath); dir_iter!=end_iter; ++dir_iter)
    {
        if(fs::is_directory(dir_iter->status()))
        {
            result = GetFullPath(fileName, dir_iter->path().string());
            if(!result.empty())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (fs::is_regular_file(dir_iter->status()))
        {
            if(dir_iter->path().filename() == fs::path(fileName).filename())
            {
                result = dir_iter->path().string();
                if(!result.empty())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```